# Get http result after httpBackend flush

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend

I have a test case that tests a service and have succeeded in checking if a get request is called in my test case :

```
 var $httpBackend, Entry, Common;



 beforeEach(module('contact_journal'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, _Entry_,_Common_,_$state_) {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    Entry = _Entry_;
    Common = _Common_;
    //$httpBackend.whenGET(URLS.entry_show_path+'?id=0').respond(200,{});

    // this is required to stub ui-router cycle on $http request
    state = _$state_;
    spyOn(state,'go');
    spyOn(state,'transitionTo');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  describe('getEntry', function(){
    it('should sent GET request', function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET(URLS.entry_show_path+'?id=0').respond(200,{});
      var result = Entry.getEntry(0);
      $httpBackend.flush();
      console.log('After flush');
      console.log(result);
      expect(result).toEqual({});
    });

  });
```

Now I want the result variable to have the response of the service so that I can check the response code is 200. But as I have done the httpBackend flush afterwards I am unable to get the result after the success callBack executes instead the success gives me a promise.
How do I get the result from my Entry.getEntry service call? Following is my service method :

```
entryService.getEntry = function(entry_id) {
    show_page_loader();
    return $http.get(URLS.entry_show_path, {params: { id: entry_id }})
      .success(function(result){
        console.log('In success');
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log('In error');
        Common.common_flash_error_message();
        console.log('error completed');
      });
  };
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the return value is a promise, you need handle it while unit testing. Here is how you can do it:

```
 it('should sent GET request', function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET(URLS.entry_show_path+'?id=0').respond(200,{});
      var result;
      Entry.getEntry(0).then(function(data) {
           result=data;
      })
      $httpBackend.flush();
      console.log('After flush');
      console.log(result);
      expect(result).toEqual({});
    });
```

Comment: I think you miss a $digest call for the promise to be unwrapped.

Comment: Its for service not controller, I don't think its needed. :)

Comment: I believe flush method will internally call it. But yes otherwise we need digest. @ashish it does not matter if it is a controller or service, someone needs to call it in unit test.